# Aggregate arrays of arrays in BigQuery

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

We can use ARRAY_AGG to aggregate rows into arrays. Is there a way to aggregate arrays of arrays? It threw error that ARRAY_AGG can't work on arrays. Thanks

Comment: use `array_concat_agg()` function